# Mysql select list after a specific id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a solution to select a list of rows coming after a certain Id from an ordered list.

For example, first I select 1000 rows. Then, on a subsequent request,  i want to fetch another 1000 rows coming from after the last id of the first request. I know i can do it with limit, but suppose there has been 100 rows added between the first and second request, there will be 100 rows that will be from the first request.

Both queries will be ordered by the date of the entries.

Here's an example of the query I thought of:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id AFTER $id ORDER BY date DESC";
```

Comment: First of all `WHERE id > $id`

Comment: @Popnoodles ok sorry but I was just trying to show a concept. So please do you have a solution? Or am I just straight dreaming because it's impossible

Comment: Hang on, is what you're actually asking "how do i paginate results?"

Answer (score 6):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` > '$id' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1000";
```

Comment: Well thank you. I feel stupid because I thought the 'id' > $id would evaluate on their numeric values and not their order in the list

Comment: It will evaluate their numeric value. Is id not an auto-incremental column? By what are you qualifying their "order in the list."

Comment: The list can is ordered by date and Yeah its an auto-incremental column but suppose I change for a randomly generated Id, that wouldn't work

Comment: You're ordering by the date column in your query, but if the id column is your key and auto incrementing then your database is "ordered by" id. Doing a query for all (*) and then limiting it by 1000 returns the first 1000 in your database according to your key, regardless of ordering by date in the query. You could insert 100 more and as long as you let the id auto increment the next 1000 in your database should still be the same as they would've been before inserting 100 new rows.

Comment: It works well for a "Recently added" list but let's say for a popular list, the Ids wouldn't be increasing

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this:

### WHERE

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` > '$id' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $length"
```

### LIMIT

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $start, $length"
```

Comment: The first way doesn't provide a limit and therefore would provide over 1000 results.

Answer (score 2):

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` > $id ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 1000";

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about logic, not code so here it is.

The first request selects the first 1000.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM the_table ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 0,1000";
```

*NB date is a reserved word so needs escaping if you've called a column "date" which you shouldn't.*

```
$rs=$db->selectMany($query); // replace this with however you select the rows. $rs is results set
```

Do stuff with PHP and save the maximum id. They may not be in order.

```
$maxid=0;

foreach ($rs as $r){
    // whatever you need to do with your results
    $maxid=max($maxid, $r->id);
}
```

Your subsequent select uses the last id

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE id > $maxid ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,1000";
```

**BUT** you need to take note that you're ordering by date and using id to find a breakpoint which sounds like it would cause data to be missed.

Perhaps you mean to use `WHERE``date``> $maxdate`? If so you can figure that out from the code given.