# UNION ALL performance tuning for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

I'm using the following SQL to fetch `posts` for each user by the user_id.

```
(select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 10) 
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 20)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 30)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 40)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 0)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 0)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 0)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 10)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 0)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 0)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 10)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 0)
union all (select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?) limit 10 offset 0)
```

The `limit ? offset ?` parts are used for the pagination for each user's posts.

For example `limit 10 offset 20` means get "10 posts per page and page 3" for the specific user.

My Question is do I have better solution for this instead of `union all` to improve the querying performance? Obviously this SQL have too many sub queries…

plus, here is the context and requirements for my use case.

- One query get both the **user** and the **user's posts**.
- Each **user** can have multiple **posts**.
- Each of the `?` is a different `user_id`.
- The `limit ? offset ?` can vary, but most of the time, the same value for each user.

Comment: Can you give us some context regarding how you are executing these queries?  Is it all at once, or one at a time?  Also, what would be filling those `?` placeholders, and would it also be the same value(s)?

Comment: Why do you need to get different pages for different users at the same time?

Comment: Using LIMIT and OFFSET without ORDER BY doesn't make much sense.

Comment: First you should avoid using `SELECT *` and get only relevant columns (as required by your application code), by specifying their names. Read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thanks! I added some extra description for this question.

Comment: @Barmar Hi, can you give some example code? Thanks!

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya  Because this is a ORM implementation I have no other choices.

Comment: @yaquawa I am pretty sure that in an ORM, you can specify which fields to fetch

Comment: @yaquawa If you're doing paging based on the dates of the posts, you should use something like `ORDER BY date_posted DESC` to get the newest posts first. Without `ORDER BY`, the criteria for paging is unpredictable and might not even be consistent from one query to the next.

Comment: `OFFSET` is a performance killer by definition. If you need performance use index pagination with `ORDER BY` instead.

Comment: @The Impaler What do you mean by `index pagination`?

Comment: @yaquawa I meant "key set" pagination. The efficient way of paginating is by using a unique set of columns to order and paginate with, so you avoid using the *evil* `OFFSET`.

Comment: @The Impaler Never heard about that.. Do you mean something like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540670/mysql-select-list-after-a-specific-id